# Changing the html of a td tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

When the edit function is triggered the td with id "promo1" changes its html to show the options save delete rule and cancel. cancel is in an a tag with an onclick function called "cancel()". When clicked this should revert the td tag "promo1" back to the image set. However this doesnt work when the onclick is coming from the cancel a tag in the td tag "promo1" but it works when the cancel() function is triggered from the Cancel Button, any clues as to why this is occurring and fixes?

```js
function edit(stringID){
  console.log (stringID);
  var id = '#promo' + stringID;
  $("#promo1").html("<div style='width:200px'><a onclick='save()' style='margin-right:10px'><b>Save</b></a> <a onclick='save()' style='margin-right:10px'><b>Delete Rule</b></a> <a onclick='cancel()'><b>Cancel</b></a><div>");
}

function cancel() {
  $("#promo1").html("<img src='dist/img/editButton.png'>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;">
          <td data-field="margin">15%</td>
            <td data-field="promo">Promotion Role 1</td>
            <td id="promo1" onclick="edit('1')" style="float:right"><img src="dist/img/editButton.png"></td>
          </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="cancel()">Cancel Button</button>
```

Comment: you don't have a `id="promo1"` in your html, so `$('#promo1')` doesn't find anything.

Comment: `$("#promo1")` and luckily you don't have any `#promo1` `8D` Also wwwhy  are you showing us some `edit` function which is useless in your [mcve] (*not*)

Comment: You have no 'promo1' ID in your HTML structure and you have no call to edit() function.

Comment: What is `var id` used for?

Comment: I posted the wrong code snippet, take a look at it again please

Comment: The edit function is succesfully triggered and changes the html to show "Save, Delete rule, Cancel", the problem is the cancel a tag doesnt change it back to show the editButton image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
function edit(stringID){
  console.log (stringID);
  var id = '#promo' + stringID;
  $("#promo1").html("<div style='width:200px'><a onclick='save()' style='margin-right:10px'><b>Save</b></a> <a onclick='save()' style='margin-right:10px'><b>Delete Rule</b></a> <a onclick='cancel()'><b>Cancel</b></a><div>");
}

function cancel() {
  $("#promo1").html("<img src='dist/img/editButton.png' onclick='edit(1)'>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
   <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;">
     <td data-field="margin">15%</td>
     <td data-field="promo">Promotion Role 1</td>
     <td id="promo1" style="float:right"><img src="dist/img/editButton.png" onclick="edit(1)"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="cancel()">Cancel Button</button>
```

Use `onclick` event on `<img>` instead of `<td>` and also include `onclick='edit(1)'` in your `cancel()`. Rest of your code works fine.